# What is the Origin and physical meaning of R- multiplet and S-multiplet in Sugra?

Tags: supergravity

In this summer, i learnt about various muliplet in Supergravity. 
First i summarize what i learn from the school.

(i) Ferrar-Zumino multiplet

The super-current multiplet satisfies 
\begin{align}
\bar{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}J_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}  = D_\alpha \Phi
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is chiral superfield.

This multiplet couples to old-minimal supergravity which has redundant $6=4+2$ degrees of freedom of bosonic variable.

(ii) R - multiplet

The super-current multiplet satisfies 
\begin{align}
\bar{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}J_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}  = W_\alpha
\end{align}
with 
\begin{align}
\bar{D}_{\dot{\beta}} W_\alpha = D^\alpha W_\alpha = \bar{D}^{\dot{\alpha}} \bar{W}_{\dot{\alpha}}=0
\end{align}

This multiplet couples to new-minimal supergravity which has redudant $6=3+3$ degrees of freedom of bosonic variable.
**(And the lecture says it is related with $R$-symmetry. How?)**

(iii)  S-multiplet

The super-current multiplet satisfies 
\begin{align}
\bar{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}J_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}  = D_\alpha \Phi + W_\alpha
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is chiral superfield.

It has $(16,16)$ multiplet.  The name $S$ is something to do with Seiberg.
And it couples to non-minimal supergravity models.

**(Is the $S$ relateds with Seiberg duality?, )**

---

Can anyone can explain detail about meaning of super-current equation for each multiplet, and if possible various viewpoint of these supergravity multiplet? (bolded parts are also my question arise from the school)

Comment: Do you have a reference from the school? I happen to be studying some of this stuff now, and I'd appreciate learning about more references. Meanwhile, there is a paper by Komargodski and Seiberg (http://inspirehep.net/record/845663) which might be useful.